# QDate has incomplete type, declaring as private member

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to create two private variables type date on a class but i'm getting the error "field 'date1' has incomplete type 'QDate'". I made an empty test application to show the problem.

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
  class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~MainWindow();

private:
  Ui::MainWindow *ui;

  QDate date1;  <<---- Problem here
  QDate date2;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Is there a special way to declare date variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding the header

```
#include <QDate>
```

you can initialize them like this:

```
QDate date1(1995,2,2);
```

Comment: Thanks very much, i could not initialize on the header of the function, complaint of an unexpected "(". But adding including QDate i was able to compile. I have the initialization of the variable in the body of the fiunction.

Comment: You're welcome and glad you handled it! Please accept it as an answer if you are done with your problem after this post.

Comment: If you initialize your data-member in the cpp file, you can use forward-declaration in your header instead of including QDate.